# Visual studio Continuous Delivery options missing

Tags: visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I am trying to make a continuous deployment of dotnet core 2.0 app in visual studio 2017 community as per https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/T115

[The given options are specified in that video are like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAXFF.png)

But when i try

[there is no azure container registry and azure container service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENjRW.png)

How to specify these two options. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a project, make sure you **Enable Docker Support** as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have selected earlier and OS is linux, it is running in docker while debugging locally.

Comment: @developer

After selecting Enable Docker support, while publishing the project you will get the options.

Comment: at publish screen also the options are not provided. Is there any difference to community and other version of VSTS. Thank you

Comment: @developer I'm using VS 2017 community edition and it working fine.
Which version are you using?

Comment: I am unable to do this through Visual studio. Finally made some progress with the help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRVGnhHzb7E. Thank you.